# Fn::ImportValue does not like Fn::Sub in its short notation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Why is following format not working giving error "the attribute in Fn::ImportValue must be a string or a function that returns a string"?

```yaml
    Source: !Join [":", [!ImportValue [!Sub "${ProductEnvironment}-${ProductName}-IngressGreengrassProxyFunctionArn"], !ImportValue [!Sub "${ProductEnvironment}-${ProductName}-IngressGreengrassProxyFunctionAlias"]]]
```

but it works if I rewrite it as:

```yaml
    Source: !Join
      - ":"
      - - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${ProductEnvironment}-${ProductName}-IngressGreengrassProxyFunctionArn"
        - Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${ProductEnvironment}-${ProductName}-IngressGreengrassProxyFunctionAlias"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) explain:

> You can't use the short form of !ImportValue when it contains a !Sub.

AWS does not provide details of its internal implementations, why they implemented `ImportValue` this way.